# How's equilibrium possible here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation, equilibrium

Here's the question.......Two point masses $m$ and $2m$ are attached at each end of a light rod. The rod is pivoted at the center and is free to move in a vertical plane. Then find the angle $A$ when the system is in equilibrium position. And feel free to consider any additional information, you think I forgot to mention.

My doubt goes like this......the gravitational force will be more on its left arm than that of right and hence the torque. So what I think is the rod should attain vertical position with the mass $2m$ at the bottom. But that ain't what happens. Tell me where I'm wrong.[image]

Comment: initial position? released from rest or not?

Comment: Is this  Homework?

Comment: Released from initial position, the rod pivoted at the center and that is not my homework I'm working for entrance examinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer corrected, since (as pointed out by @Georg in the comments) I missed this sentence:*

> The rod is pivoted at the center

If the arms apparently are equal then **you** are right! For equal angles $A$ and arms $d$ the torque $\tau=Fd \cos(A)$ caused by the double mass is double as big. The rod will definitely reach a vertical position, $A=90^ \circ$, where both torques are zero, $\tau_1=\tau_2=0$.

> But that ain't what happens.

In that case we have not been told everything in this system. Are there more forces? Is the force $F$ not constant but varying with height?

With the stated information only (and assuming gravity acts), the bar *must* reach a vertical position.

---

If the arms were not equally long (as I thought), an non-vertical equilibrium *can* be reached.

The torques $\tau=Fd \cos(A)$ can be equal at some angle (meaning, no rotation) even with different forces $F$ if the distances $d$ to the rotation point are also different, $d_1 \neq d_2$.

Comment: Just for future reference, you don't have to (and, I guess, shouldn't) say that the answer was corrected in the answer itself. That's what the edit description field is for. The edited version of a post should read as if it were written that way from the beginning. But it's probably not worth making a whole new edit just to fix that.

Comment: Roger, over'n'out!

Answer (score 1):

### But that ain't what happens

If your rod is pivoted at the centre, then it must come to an equilibrium only in the vertical position, with mass 'm' at the top and '2m' at the bottom, in the absensce of any additional forces.

If you are sure that is not what happens, then by all probability, the rod is not pivoted at the centre and steeven has explained the case (in the above answer).

Since, you are not confident about any additional info, this is all I can say.

Comment: Alright then. Now suppose if we replace the mass "2m" with "m" and release it at an angle A=60 (between its left arm and horizontal) then it must remain at that position.

Comment: I guess you are wrong here. Think carefully, here both masses will be same and as the rod is pivoted at the center, there will be equal torques on both arms and will be canceled AT ANY POSITION. The force components will be mgcos(A) ("A" is the acute angle of the light rod with the horizontal). We're talking about ideal conditions. In your experiment friction is involved.

Comment: And the system will never oscillate. That's because the potential energy of the system (With both mass equal) is conserved at any position. (When one mass is lifted by height "h" other goes down all the same.

Comment: @Syl Sorry. I didn't make much thinking onto the case. You're right. When both masses are equal, the torques cancel at any position, and the system never oscillates. I hope my answer is right in the 2m-m case. I'm deleting the previous comment.